# C# Need code to stop exporting header row

Tags: c#

Hey guys, I have this quick bit of code that I can't figure out how to stop exporting the header row.

the results are

```
PrimaryRowGuid|Text  
| blah blah blahg blah  
blah blah blahg blahblah blah blahg blah  
blah blah blahg blah
```

I need the results to be:

```
blah blah blahg blah  
blah blah blahg blahblah blah blahg blah  
blah blah blahg blah
```

Any help is appricated!

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strm))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        writer.Write((i == 0 ? "" : "|") + reader.GetName(i));
    writer.Write("\n");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            writer.Write((i == 0 ? "" : "|") + reader[i].ToString().Replace(@"<swme> ", string.Empty).Replace(@" </swme>|", "|").Replace(@" </swme>", ";").Replace('\r', ' ').TrimEnd((char)';'));
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
    reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The header row is exported by the following lines of code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        writer.Write((i == 0 ? "" : "|") + reader.GetName(i));
    writer.Write("\n");
```

I assume you can figure out from here how to get rid of it.

Comment: Okay I understand, what do i need to do to omit that header row

Comment: Those lines of code write the header row to the file. What would happen if they weren't there?

Comment: No offense, @Mike, but that comment makes me a little worried... In either event, @SLaks's comment is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: it's a really bad day with really little time

Answer (score 1):

Just take out the reader.Read block of code and you will be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    writer.Write((i == 0 ? "" : "|") + reader.GetName(i));
writer.Write("\n");
```

Delete that block.